# MySQL - Need to get only the latest data based on the date/time column in the child table for each record in the parent table

Tags: mysql

We have two tables Spot and Spot_Log with the following data:

Spot:

```
ESN       | Department | VehicleModel   | AssignedToName
--------------------------------------------------------
0-2506698 | 23         | 2014 Equinox   | Ron
0-2507419 | 32         | 2015 Sierra    | Chuck
0-2506208 | 32         | 2015 Sierra    | Don
0-2506629 | 32         | 2014 Silverado | Jonathan
```

Spot_Log:

```
ESN_ID    | est_dt           | latitude  | longitude 
-----------------------------------------------------
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 11:08 | 43.712910 | -79.367798
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 10:43 | 43.713322 | -79.359741
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 10:39 | 43.713341 | -79.359741
0-2506629 | 20/11/2014 10:07 | 48.412701 | -89.248047
0-2506629 | 20/11/2014 10:02 | 48.412720 | -89.248047
0-2506629 | 20/11/2014 10:01 | 48.412788 | -89.248108
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 09:26 | 43.714870 | -79.357758
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 09:21 | 43.714729 | -79.357819
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 07:15 | 43.993961 | -79.229401
0-2506698 | 20/11/2014 07:11 | 44.018250 | -79.230591
0-2506629 | 19/11/2014 19:01 | 48.412682 | -89.247887
0-2506629 | 19/11/2014 16:53 | 48.412670 | -89.247993
0-2506629 | 19/11/2014 16:48 | 48.412670 | -89.247963
0-2506208 | 19/11/2014 16:43 | 48.399891 | -89.257599
0-2506629 | 19/11/2014 16:39 | 48.404961 | -89.252808
0-2506208 | 19/11/2014 16:38 | 48.399940 | -89.257721
0-2506698 | 19/11/2014 16:37 | 44.096931 | -79.129028
0-2506208 | 19/11/2014 16:33 | 48.399872 | -89.25769
0-2506698 | 19/11/2014 16:32 | 44.096951 | -79.129059
0-2506208 | 19/11/2014 16:31 | 48.402531 | -89.254089
0-2506698 | 19/11/2014 16:27 | 44.080601 | -79.15979
0-2506698 | 19/11/2014 15:07 | 43.765202 | -79.376801
0-2506698 | 19/11/2014 14:59 | 43.732059 | -79.440338
0-2507419 | 19/11/2014 14:49 | 48.399891 | -89.25766
0-2507419 | 19/11/2014 14:43 | 48.399879 | -89.25766
0-2507419 | 19/11/2014 14:38 | 48.399830 | -89.257721
0-2507419 | 19/11/2014 14:34 | 48.399899 | -89.25769
0-2507419 | 19/11/2014 14:00 | 48.399872 | -89.25766
```

All we have to do is pick the LATEST data based on the column Spot_Log.est_dt for each vehicle listed in the Spot table as follows:

```
ESN       | Department | VehicleModel   | AssignedToName | est_dt           | latitude  | longitude 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0-2506698 | 23         | 2014 Equinox   | Ron            | 20/11/2014 11:08 | 43.712910 | -79.367798
0-2507419 | 32         | 2015 Sierra    | Chuck          | 19/11/2014 14:49 | 48.399891 | -89.25766
0-2506208 | 32         | 2015 Sierra    | Don            | 19/11/2014 16:43 | 48.399891 | -89.257599
0-2506629 | 32         | 2014 Silverado | Jonathan       | 20/11/2014 10:07 | 48.412701 | -89.248047
```

Since right now there are 4 records in the Spot table it should return 4 latest records.

I have tried the following queries which shows all the rows despite DISTINCT and the join condition is mentioned

```
SELECT  s.ESN, s.AssignedToName, s.Department, sl.est_dt, sl.latitude, sl.longitude
FROM    SpotTrace s, SpotTrace_Log sl
WHERE   s.ESN = sl.ESN_ID 
ORDER   BY s.ESN, sl.est_dt DESC;

SELECT  DISTINCT s.ESN, s.AssignedToName, s.Department, sl.est_dt, sl.latitude, sl.longitude
FROM    SpotTrace s, SpotTrace_Log sl
WHERE   s.ESN = sl.ESN_ID 
ORDER   BY s.ESN, sl.est_dt DESC
```

I have also tried Limit 4 but it only shows the first 4 of all the rows as shown above.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT s.ESN, s.AssignedToName, s.Department, sl.est_dt, sl.latitude, sl.longitude
FROM    SpotTrace s, SpotTrace_Log sl
WHERE   s.ESN = sl.ESN_ID 
ORDER   BY s.ESN, sl.est_dt DESC
LIMIT   4;
```

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: It would be simpler (and orders of magnitude quicker) to use a date/datetime data type.

Comment: SpotTrace_Log.est_dt is datetime data type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from your distinct which apply on all properties.

Have you try something like:

```
SELECT s.ESN, s.AssignedToName, s.Department, sl.est_dt, sl.latitude, sl.longitude
FROM SpotTrace s
JOIN SpotTrace_Log sl on s.ESN = sl.ESN_ID AND MAX(est_dt)
ORDER BY s.ESN
```

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM spot_log x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT esn_id
            , MAX(est_dt) max_est_dt 
         FROM spot_log 
        GROUP 
           BY esn_id
     ) y 
    ON y.esn_id = x.esn_id 
   AND y.max_est_dt = x.est_dt;
```

Just join (or outer join) the other table on to this.

Comment: I fixed it myself :-)

SELECT  s.ESN, s.AssignedToID, s.AssignedToName, s.Department, sl.est_dt, sl.latitude, sl.longitude
FROM  Spot s, Spot_Log sl
WHERE   s.ESN = sl.ESN_ID 
AND   sl.est_dt IN (SELECT max_table.max_est_dt FROM( SELECT DISTINCT sl.ESN_ID, MAX(sl.est_dt) AS max_est_dt FROM Spot_Log sl GROUP BY sl.ESN_ID) AS max_table)
ORDER  BY s.ESN, sl.est_dt DESC;

Comment: Well, if you think so.

Comment: can`t seem to format the above query in a comment! But works fine